# Adding Vuetify package to Excel addin made with VueJS framework

Tags: excel, vue.js, office-js, vuetify.js, excel-addins

I tried adding a excel add-in(Side load) using VueJS and created the manifest files by using Yeoman office package. I followed the instructions by going through [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-get-started-vue). Everything worked fine, now I wanted to add Vuetify framework to my add-in application.

On the main.js file from template, the Vue instance is initiated with this code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const Office = window.Office
Office.initialize = () => { 
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {App},
    template: '<App/>'
  })
}
```

}

Now I am trying to add Vuetify and doing an npm install as per [their docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start) by modifying the above code as:

```
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import App from './App'
  import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

    Vue.use(Vuetify)
    Vue.config.productionTip = false


    const Office = window.Office
    Office.initialize = () => { 
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components: {App},
        template: '<App/>'
      })
    }
```

When I introduce the Vuetify library, the add-in is not working..I am not sure how incorporate Vuetify to my Office add-in. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uploaded an example repo with a Vue Excel addin using Vuetify:

https://github.com/beauholland/Vue-Excel-Addin

- NPM install
- NPM start
- Browse to http://localhost:3000 and confirm the web app runs in IE11

If you get this far its time to sideload the app in Excel.

- Setup sideload folder share for testing i.e. vue-excel\Graph API\ and configure Excel to trust share folder and insert addin https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins

NOTE: the sample app in my repo is called "Graph API"

Answer (score 0):

Recently got Vuetify working within an Excel Addin in Windows.

- Are you on a Windows box?
- Can you browse to your app i.e. http://localhost:3000 successfully?
- Can you browse to your app i.e. http://localhost:3000 successfully within IE11?
- Do you see any errors in your browser dev tools console?
- What does "the add-in is not working" mean, any more specifics about the problem?

Issue I had was related to Vuetify IE11 compatibility, specifically...

> Vuetify utilizes features of ES2015/2017 that require the need to use polyfills for Internet Explorer 11

Source: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#ie11-safari-9-support

As far as I am aware Excel addins require IE11 i.e. Office for Windows as at both 2013 and 2016 use an embedded IE11 instance to host add-ins.

> Internet Explorer 11 or later, which must be installed but doesn't have to be the default browser. To support Office Add-ins, the Office client that acts as host uses browser components that are part of Internet Explorer 11 or later.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/requirements-for-running-office-add-ins

Source: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/31155925-office-add-ins-should-run-in-edge-not-ie11

Comment: Thanks @Beau! To answer your questions:

Comment: Are you on a Windows box? I am not sure what you mean by this, I am trying out to get the add-in working in the sideload of MS office. Can you browse to your app i.e. http://localhost:3000 successfully? Yes, but without vuetify. Can you browse to your app i.e. http://localhost:3000 successfully within IE11? Yes, again without vuetify. Do you see any errors in your browser dev tools console? I just a blank page without any errors. I tried to install babael polyfills and I am getting the same results...

Comment: Thanks once again @Beau!:) Really appreciate your help. Sorry about the poor formatting in my earlier reply

Comment: @Dennis please mark as answered so we can close this out.